Linker complains about multiple definitions
I have been staring at this too long and may just not be seeing something obvious.
I am cross-compiling on Ubuntu 24.04 using /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-12 cross-compiler for Raspberry Pi Zero2 W.I have had things working fine. I wanted to create a map that just contains some delay values for the device I am accessing. In the include file I have:
    154 typedef enum {
    155   SHT4X_TIMING_SOFT_RESET,
    156   SHT4X_TIMING_MEASUREMENT_LOW_REPEATABILITY,
    157   SHT4X_TIMING_MEASUREMENT_MED_REPEATABILITY,
    158   SHT4X_TIMING_MEASUREMENT_HIGH_REPEATABILITY,
    159   SHT4X_TIMING_HEATER_DURATION_LONG,
    160   SHT4X_TIMING_HEATER_DURATION_SHORT,
    161 } Sht4xMaxTimings;
    162 
    163 /*
    164  * These are in microseonds
    165  */
    166 map<Sht4xMaxTimings, int> sht4x_min_delays = {
    167     {SHT4X_TIMING_SOFT_RESET,1000}, /* tpu 1 millisecond */
    168     /*
    169      * For the next 3 the table says including tpu. I take that
    170      * to mean I should add the value above, tpu, to these values
    171      * in the table. I may have that wrong though.
    172      */
    173     {SHT4X_TIMING_MEASUREMENT_LOW_REPEATABILITY, 1600 + 1000}, /* 1.6 millisecond  + tpu = 2.6 milliseconds*/
    174     {SHT4X_TIMING_MEASUREMENT_MED_REPEATABILITY, 500 + 1000}, /* 4.5 milliseconds + tpu = 5.5 milliseconds */
    175     {SHT4X_TIMING_MEASUREMENT_HIGH_REPEATABILITY, 8300 + 1000}, /* 8.3 milliseconds + tpu = 9.3 milliseconds */
    176     {SHT4X_TIMING_HEATER_DURATION_LONG, 1100000},     /* 1.1 seconds */
    177     {SHT4X_TIMING_HEATER_DURATION_SHORT, 110000}   /* 0.11 seconds */
    178 };

These values just get passed to a usleep() depending on the command called. Right now I have all the usleep() command lines commented out just to make sure the only chance a variable with this name that the compiler sees is defined on line 166. When I compile here is the error I get:
[main] Building folder: /home/chrisk/Projects/RaspberryPi/WS/build 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/chrisk/Projects/RaspberryPi/WS/build --config Debug --target all --
[build] [2/4  25% :: 0.757] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/WeatherStation.dir/main.cpp.o
[build] [2/4  50% :: 0.878] Building CXX object src/lib/devices/i2c/CMakeFiles/i2cdevices.dir/sht4x.cpp.o
[build] [3/4  75% :: 0.931] Linking CXX static library src/lib/devices/i2c/libi2cdevices.a
[build] [4/4 100% :: 1.044] Linking CXX executable src/WeatherStation
[build] FAILED: src/WeatherStation 
[build] : && /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-12 --sysroot=/opt/sdk/rpi_zero_2_w -g  src/CMakeFiles/WeatherStation.dir/main.cpp.o -o src/WeatherStation  src/lib/devices/i2c/libi2cdevices.a  src/lib/units/libunits.a && :
[build] /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: src/lib/devices/i2c/libi2cdevices.a(sht4x.cpp.o):/home/chrisk/Projects/RaspberryPi/WS/src/lib/devices/i2c/include/sht4x.h:166: multiple definition of `sht4x_min_delays'; src/CMakeFiles/WeatherStation.dir/main.cpp.o:/home/chrisk/Projects/RaspberryPi/WS/src/lib/devices/i2c/include/sht4x.h:166: first defined here
[build] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[proc] The command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/chrisk/Projects/RaspberryPi/WS/build --config Debug --target all -- exited with code: 1
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:01.069
[build] Build finished with exit code 1

So, the linker thinks sht4x_min_delay has been defined multiple times. It shows that the first time it was defined is on line 166 above. It doesn;t bother to tell me where else it got defined.
I have tried to change the variable name sht4x_min_delays and then it says that name has multiple definitions. I have grepped through all files in the project and this is the only place sht4x_min_delays is found, other then the ones I have commented out.
I have done make clean and then re-built and still get the same error. The sht4x.h file has a proper guard to make sure it doesn't get included twice:
'''
#ifndef SRC_LIB_DEVICES_I2C_INCLUDE_SHT4X_H_
#define SRC_LIB_DEVICES_I2C_INCLUDE_SHT4X_H_
<bunch o stuff>
#endif

'''
So, I am confused why the linker thinks there are multiple definitions.
Any ideas would be helpful

There are multiple definitions because the header file is included in multiple translation units, each of which then has one definition of the variable. Definitions of variables should generally be either in a .cpp file or be marked inline, just like definitions for functions.

Incidentally, that typedef enum … Sht4xMaxTimings is a C thing. In C++ enum Sht4xMaxTimings … works just fine.

Well I just added a const in front of the definition, which is what I want since nothing will change and now it compiles.
const map<Sht4xMaxTimings, int> sht4x_min_delays = {
    {SHT4X_TIMING_SOFT_RESET,1000}, /* tpu 1 millisecond */
    /*
     * For the next 3 the table says including tpu. I take that
     * to mean I should add the value above, tpu, to these values
     * in the table. I may have that wrong though.
     */
    {SHT4X_TIMING_MEASUREMENT_LOW_REPEATABILITY, 1600 + 1000}, /* 1.6 millisecond  + tpu = 2.6 milliseconds*/
    {SHT4X_TIMING_MEASUREMENT_MED_REPEATABILITY, 500 + 1000}, /* 4.5 milliseconds + tpu = 5.5 milliseconds */
    {SHT4X_TIMING_MEASUREMENT_HIGH_REPEATABILITY, 8300 + 1000}, /* 8.3 milliseconds + tpu = 9.3 milliseconds */
    {SHT4X_TIMING_HEATER_DURATION_LONG, 1100000},     /* 1.1 seconds */
    {SHT4X_TIMING_HEATER_DURATION_SHORT, 110000}   /* 0.11 seconds */
};


Now it compiles with no problem:
[main] Building folder: /home/chrisk/Projects/RaspberryPi/WS/build 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/chrisk/Projects/RaspberryPi/WS/build --config Debug --target all --
[build] [2/4  25% :: 1.081] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/WeatherStation.dir/main.cpp.o
[build] [2/4  50% :: 1.180] Building CXX object src/lib/devices/i2c/CMakeFiles/i2cdevices.dir/sht4x.cpp.o
[build] [3/4  75% :: 1.245] Linking CXX static library src/lib/devices/i2c/libi2cdevices.a
[build] [4/4 100% :: 1.329] Linking CXX executable src/WeatherStation
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:01.369
[build] Build finished with exit code 0

I can't say I am real sure why marking it as a constant changes things, but since I want it to be a constant it works for me.

The const is part of the signature and all parts of the signature must match.

Marking the variable const solves the issue, because const variables have internal linkage by default in C++, i.e. if the definition appears in multiple translation units, then each definition will define a different variable in each translation unit rather than defining the same variable as is the behavior of the (otherwise) default external linkage.

const objects by default have file scope; non-const objects by default have global scope. Defining sht4x_min_delays in a header means that every source file that #includes that header will have its own sht4x_min_delays object. When the objects are global you have multiple definitions. When they’re in file scope you have multiple independent copies. Don’t define objects in header files.
